Why do some file titles have a • rather than an x to close?
Most open files in Lapce have an "x" by their title to close the tab that is showing the file. If the file is dirty (ie has been changed but not saved) the title is in italics. But sometimes the "x" is replaced with a "•" and the file won't close or save. Why would this happen? Is this a feature for which I can't find any documentation?
I tried saving. I clicked on the bullet and it prompted me to save, discard or cancel and then ignored what I chose (ie defaulted to cancel). In the end I either closed Lapce or clicked on the bullet enough times to cause Lapce to crash out. The .lapce directory in the project only has plugins/crates-lsp/ in it.

This is because the file has been modified and is not yet saved.
Saving the file should replace the • with an x.
